# Is it possible that I already exceeded the limit of query for Google Maps Static in just an hour of testing?

Tags: api, google-maps-static-api

I just started playing with the Google Map API for Static Images, and in just an hour it has appeared this image:

http://www.coon.it/drop/limit.png

Is that normal?

My page need 6 static image, that means that I call it, like 170 times?
I don't think it's possible since the pictures are always the same and the documentation says that if i call the same image it doesn't count.

What can i do?
Thank you

Comment: If you're using Static Maps, it's not the Maps API. It's not entirely clear from your question which API you are using. If I've got the new tags wrong, please feel free to correct them (but it would help to make that clear in the question, too).

Comment: ok, thank you. Sorry I'm new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there is an absolute limit on the number of images, that limit may be calculated over a shorter period than 24 hours. 2400/day could be interpreted as 100/hour, so you can't use all 2400 in one go [I can't remember what the limit is for Static Maps, but you get the idea].

With most Google services there is also a rate limit, and it's possible that fetching six images almost simultaneously breaks the rate limit. Rate limits vary depending on server load, but spacing requests out to 200ms should be ok.

Or it may look like an automated image-fetcher (especially if you have run it 30 times in the last hour). Google don't like automated crawlers either.

Answer (score 0):

What should it display? With me it just displays a landscape with a row of trees(what i gues is what you want to see?).